# CKEditor for ASP.Net does not respect element visibility

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ckeditor

I've been tasked with dragging an ASP.Net 2.0 WebForms app kicking and screaming into the 20th century. Part of my very first release is to handle interactive control visibility on the client, without postbacks, and replacing Infragistics 9 rich text controls with [CKEditor for .Net](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Integration_Advanced) (Built around CK3.x rather than CK4.x).

Setting initial state

```
$(function(){
    switch($('select#category').val()){
        ...
        default:
            $('textarea#comments').hide()
    }
}
```

Part of the JS injected by `CKEditorControl.PreRender`:

```
(function () {
    if (typeof CKEDITOR != 'undefined') {
        var d = document.getElementById('#this.ClientID#');
        if (d) d.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    ...
```

It seems to me that this control-ized version of CKEditor is coded with the assumption that inputs will be visible by default.

**Is there a better .Net wrapper for CKEditor, or a patch to fix this failure to coexist with other code?**

Comment: How about not using a wrapper? I have an mvc3 app and I think it's easier to code simple ajax calls rather than deal with a wrapper :p

Comment: I was hoping for a quick switch with minimal impact, hence swapping one .Net WebControl for another. This bug has emerged on the day I was hoping to declare it all "ready for test", so changing the structure of the page is not an option

Comment: In that case, I would try to contact cksource support and file an issue in their trac at http://dev.ckeditor.com/ - I'm not aware of any other .net wrappers :C